# Exportar conversaciones de whatsapp a formato plano .txt

Tags: whatsapp

Necesito exportar mis conversaciones de whatsapp a un formato en el cual pueda hacer analítica de datos

Actualmente el proceso que uso es

> ```
>  Para enviar tu historial de chats por correo electrónico, sigue estos pasos:
>  1.   Abre el chat que quieras enviar por correo electrónico. 
>  2.   Toca Más opciones. 
>  3.   Toca Más. 
>  4.   Toca Exportar chat. 
>  5.   Elige SIN ARCHIVOS o INCLUIR ARCHIVOS. 
>  6.   Selecciona la aplicación de onedrive y cargar.
> ```
>
> El correo electrónico se enviará como un texto. Cuando se envía el
>   historial con archivos adjuntos, solo se envían los 10 000 mensajes
>   más recientes. Sin archivos, puedes enviar hasta los 40 000 mensajes
>   más recientes. Estas restricciones se deben al tamaño máximo del
>   correo electrónico.

Este proceso me exige hacerlo conversación por conversación de manera manualmente; Quiero saber si existe algún proceso mas eficiente para obtener esta información

Comment: Tu pregunta está relacionada de alguna forma con programación?

Comment: Va relacionada a los procesos, pido recomendaciones..  si es mas viable un scraper del path de whatsapp web que no encripta o existe alguna forma de programar desde android... cualquier forma que se les ocurra para automatizar ese proceso.... realmente he buscado y me he quedado sin ideas.

Comment: En android whatsapp almacena los datos en una carpeta, yo encriptaria esa carpeta y enviaria todo.

Comment: @Shassain, ¿donde encuentro esa carpeta?, no la he encontrado en el drive que tengo sincronizado